# APCUPSD APC Back-UPS 650mi Serial to USB on RaspberryPI 4

Tags: raspberry-pi4

Despite hours of searches and several attempts, I cannot configure `apcupsd` to manage my UPS.

This is my UPS:
https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/BK650MI/apc-backups-650va-230v/

My configuration:

1. Raspberry Pi 4, 5.10.63-v7l+
2. Serial to USB Cable, correctly configured:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 067b:23c3 Prolific Technology, Inc. USB-Serial Controller
```

3. The port is configured correctly:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -ltra /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 80 Dec 29 23:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 Dec 29 23:05 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 29 23:05 usb-Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller_BRA_h10CD20-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

4. I tried every possible configuration in the `apcupsd.conf` file. The furthest I went in terms of results from testing was with the following:

```
UPSCABLE simple
UPSTYPE dumb
DEVICE /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But even then, the every option under `apctest` fails: `Illegal response.`

I followed these guides:

- https://gist.github.com/Thermionix/2715786
- https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-908274.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a programming question suitable for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: You are right...I was just desperate

Answer (score 0):

When you say serial to USB cable correctly configured do you mean that you are using APC cable 940-0020C or equivalently wired cable? It's not a straight through cable but you can find wiring diagrams to make one yourself online.

Just plugging a standard USB to serial cable straight in won't work without the "magic" cable however I have the official cable and also have an APC BK650MI connected to a Pi running apcupsd (Raspberry Pi OS) and monitoring works fine for me. Config should be

```
UPSCABLE 940-0020C
UPSTYPE dumb
DEVICE /dev/ttyUSB0
```